# Modifying a Variables Value from a string with the variables name

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

If I had the following code:

```
random_variable = "Hello World"
new_value = "It Works!"
```

And I had something like this:

```
def set_variable_value(var_name, new_value):
    // Code here
    pass
```

Is it possible to have a function like the one above where `var_name` is a string? It should take `var_name` and find a variable named the value of the string, and change the value to whatever new_value is.

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I searched the web for a while now and discovered nothing related to my issue. (Google is being useless as usual)

Thanks

Comment: You'll want a dictionary. `my_data = {"random_variable": "Old value"}` ...

Comment: Do not modify variable name dynamically, this **will** cause you more trouble than you expect to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```py
def set_variable_value(var_name, new_value):
    globals()[var_name] = new_value
```

However, this could be considered an anti-pattern. Consider using a dictionary instead and using the values as `my_dictionary[some_string]`.

Comment: Please do not suggest this, it has to many unexpected consequences and should be avoided for any general use case.

Comment: well... I don't want to use a dictionary... and I mean... it works... so why not

Comment: @Eric because you should avoid well understood antipatterns

Comment: @Eric note you actually *are* using a dictionary, just that dictionary happens to be the global namespace.

Comment: oh... well in that case... ok